# Android Gradle Plugin 3.1 giving error in Merged manifest while running instant run

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to migrate my Android project from version 2.3 to 3.1. I am having 2 different `productFlavors` - free and premium.

Before migrating to the latest Android Gradle Plugin, everything was working fine, but after migrating I am getting the following error.

```
:app:compileLoggedVariantQaDebugJavaWithJavac
/app/build/intermediates/manifests/instant-run/free/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:74: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka com.example:mipmap/icon) not found.
```

I have an `AndroidManifest.xml` which is located in app/src/main. Apart from that my two `flavors` free and premium have two manifest files at `app/src/free` and `app/src/premium` respectively. They just add some `<uses-permission>` tags. Apart from that, everything else is same.

Also, this only happens when instant run is enabled. If Instant run is disabled, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> AndroidManifest.xml:74: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka
>   com.example:mipmap/icon) not found.

Try deleting the `intermediates` folder in `/app/build/intermediates`.

Because this is in *debug mode* and you can delete it then rebuild the project and it'll be good to go after that. It also came from `manifests/instant-run` as you can see.

Comment: I tried clean build, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Did you check your `mipmap/icon` for this file? Does it exist?

Comment: yeah, as I told, it works when I disable instant run. so obviously that icon exists. Only when instant run is enabled, I face this issue.

Comment: Issue is in `app/src/free` Manifest which is locating like this: `com.example:mipmap/icon` maybe the location is wrong or maybe a bug since you said it works without instant run! Weird! Reinvalidates caches and restart might help ...